# CENTOS 6.5 x86_64 fails to install httpd using yum

Tags: linux, apache-2.2, centos6.5

I am trying to install apache httpd but it fails

```
root@web [/]# yum install httpd
Loaded plugins: downloadonly, fastestmirror, replace
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * epel: mirror.compevo.com
 * remi-php56: mirror.pw
 * remi-test: mirror.pw
 * List item
Setting up Install Process
No package httpd available.
Error: Nothing to do
```

**Edit**: Here is the repolist

```
root@web [/]# yum repolist
Loaded plugins: downloadonly, fastestmirror, replace
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
epel/metalink                                                      |  16 kB     00:00
 * epel: mirror.compevo.com
 * remi-php56: mirror.pw
 * remi-test: mirror.pw
remi-debuginfo                                                     | 2.9 kB     00:00
remi-php55-debuginfo                                               | 2.9 kB     00:00
remi-php56                                                         | 2.9 kB     00:00
remi-php56-debuginfo                                               | 2.9 kB     00:00
remi-test                                                          | 2.9 kB     00:00
remi-test-debuginfo                                                | 2.9 kB     00:00

repo id              repo name                                                  status
epel                 Extra Packages for Enterprise Linux 6 - x86_64             10,217+881
remi-debuginfo       Les RPM de remi pour Enterprise Linux 6 - x86_64 - debugin     31+550
remi-php55-debuginfo Les RPM de remi de PHP 5.5 pour Enterprise Linux 6 - x86_6      0+207
remi-php56           Les RPM de remi de PHP 5.6 pour Enterprise Linux 6 - x86_6      6+316
remi-php56-debuginfo Les RPM de remi de PHP 5.6 pour Enterprise Linux 6 - x86_6      0+215
remi-test            Les RPM de remi en test pour Enterprise Linux 6 - x86_64        29+66
remi-test-debuginfo  Les RPM de remi en test pour Enterprise Linux 6 - x86_64 -       4+16
repolist: 10,287

root@web [/]# cat /etc/yum.repos.d/CentOS-Base.repo
cat: /etc/yum.repos.d/CentOS-Base.repo: No such file or directory
root@web [/]#
```

I used the link http://www.if-not-true-then-false.com/2010/install-apache-php-on-fedora-centos-red-hat-rhel/ to install

I downloaded centos-release-6-5 and installed using rpm -ivh . The result is as below

```
root@web [/]# rpm -ivh http://anorien.csc.warwick.ac.uk/mirrors/centos/6.5/os/x86_64/Packages/centos-release-6-5.el6.centos.11.1.x86_64.rpm

Retrieving  anorien.csc.warwick.ac.uk/mirrors/centos/6.5/os/x86_64/Packages/centos-release-6-5.el6.centos.11.1.x86_64.rpm

Preparing...                ########################################### [100%]

        package centos-release-6-5.el6.centos.11.2.x86_64 (which is newer than centos-release-6-5.el6.centos.11.1.x86_64) is already installed

        file /etc/yum.repos.d/CentOS-Vault.repo from install of centos-release-6-5.el6.centos.11.1.x86_64 conflicts with file from package centos-release-6-5.el6.centos.11.2.x86_64
```

I tried using -Uvh and the result is same

```
root@web [/]# rpm -Uvh centos-release-6-5.el6.centos.11.1.x86_64.rpm
Preparing...                ########################################### [100%]
        package centos-release-6-5.el6.centos.11.2.x86_64 (which is newer than centos-release-6-5.el6.centos.11.1.x86_64) is already installed
root@web [/]#
```

Comment: What has happened to your `base` repository?  Why is it disabled or missing?  Could you **edit into your question** the outputs of `yum repolist` and `cat /etc/yum.repos.d/CentOS-Base.repo`?

Comment: MadHatter is right... you are missing all the CentOS related repos

Comment: See [my comment](http://serverfault.com/questions/634136/centos-6-5-x86-64-fails-to-install-httpd-using-yum#comment763315_634153) below.

Comment: Yes  Michael Hampton, I used your format rpm -Uvh --oldpackage .  Failed to retrieve base and updates repos back

Answer (score 2):

I have no idea how, but someone has managed to delete your `base` and `updates` repos, which gives you the operating system itself.  All you're left with is a bunch of extended repos that provide more up-to-date versions of certain tools.  That isn't going to work.

The package that owns the repo file you need is called `centos-release-6-5`, and your best bet is to get it from one of the mirrors.  It's a small file, so it doesn't much mater which one.  Try downloading http://anorien.csc.warwick.ac.uk/mirrors/centos/6.5/os/x86_64/Packages/centos-release-6-5.el6.centos.11.1.x86_64.rpm and installing it with `rpm -Uvh --oldpackage`; that should give you the base and updates repos back, and after that both installing `httpd` and doing general `updates` should work much better.

And please, if you're going to be a regular here, learn to use our markup system.  It's pretty simple.

Comment: **Please, edit this into your question, and make sure you get the formatting right.**  It's unreadable, otherwise.  But if thie issue is `rpm` refusing to install because some of the files from the old package are still around, add ``--force`` to the `rpm` command.  You **need** those `base` and `updates` repos back.

Comment: You need to use `rpm -Uvh --oldpackage` in this scenario, _not_ `rpm -ivh`.

Comment: D'oh!  You are, of course, completely right, and I've amended accordingly.  Thanks!